# Building uberjar with gradle fails in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, uberjar

Hi I'm using gradle to create a fat jar.
It works properly on my local machine but fails when running from Jenkins.

My local gradle version is: GradleVersion.current().getVersion()=2.2.1
The one in Jenkins: GradleVersion.current().getVersion()=2.4

build.gradle looks like

Is there anything about gradle version?

I just run tasks: clean uberjar

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
def classifier = 'producao'

println "GradleVersion.current().getVersion()="+ GradleVersion.current().getVersion()

println "Project env = '${project.hasProperty('env')}'"

// para passar parametros -Penv=homologacao

if (project.hasProperty('env') && project.getProperty('env') == 'homologacao') {
    classifier = 'homologacao'
}
println "Classifier = ${classifier}"
println "Using 'com.mundi:OneStop:1.0:${classifier}'"
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.10'
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    compile  'net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3'
    compile "com.mundi:OneStop:1.0:${classifier}"
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.3"
}

task listJars << {
    configurations.compile.each { File file -> println file.name }
}

test { systemProperties 'property': 'value' }

uploadArchives {
    repositories { flatDir { dirs 'repos'
        } }
}

task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "build/classes/main"

    sourceSets {
        main { resources { srcDir 'src/main/resources' } }
    }

    from sourceSets.main.resources
}

task uberjar(type: Jar, group:'Extra Jars', description: 'Assembles a single uber jar archive containing the main classes along with all its dependencies.', 
    dependsOn:[':copyToLib',
    ':compileJava',
    ':compileGroovy',
    ':processResources'
]) {
    classifier = 'uber'
    destinationDir new File("$buildDir")
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from(configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) { 

        //exclude all META-INF that may appear in any dependant jar         
        exclude "META-INF/**"     
    }

    version = '1.0'

    baseName = "OneStopMonitor"

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class':  "com.onestop.monitor.AirMonitor",
        'Implementation-Title': 'OneStop Monitor',
        'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}
group = 'com.onestop'
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file:///Users/eduardorodrigues/.m2/repository")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try locally with gradle v2.4? You should bundle gradle wrapper with your application to get around this exact issue of different gradle versions in different environments.

Comment: I add gradlew to the project and I although it's running with the same version of my dev environment, I still don't get the fat jar. I noticed that the folder build/tmp/expandedArchives/ only contains the dependencies declared within the build.gradle

Comment: Please post the error your seeing. Try running with --stacktrace for more info

Comment: there is no error msg

Comment: Does the Jenkins user have permission to write to file:///Users/eduardorodrigues/.m2 ?

Comment: yes, it does. I use fat jar with maven and it does work perfectly

Comment: yes, all the other projects work perfect

Comment: after lots of teste I still cannot get it to work.

Comment: You have two steps, one is to create the jar in $buildDir and then publish it to .m2. Both of them don't work? No `-uber` jar in buildDir?